# Pode causar ciclos ou vários caminhos em cascata. Especifique ON DELETE NO ACTION ou ON UPDATE NO ACTION, ou modifique outras restrições FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho uma classe que vai ter duas FK apontando para a mesma tabela, então, o Entity Framework retorna o erro:

> Pode causar ciclos ou vários caminhos em cascata. Especifique ON DELETE NO ACTION ou ON UPDATE NO ACTION, ou modifique outras restrições FOREIGN KEY.

```
[ForeignKey("TestePaiId")]
public virtual Teste TestePai { get; set; }
public int TestePaiId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TesteFilhoId")]
public virtual Teste TesteFilho{ get; set; }
public int TesteFilhoId{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Resolvi usando essa código: modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); dentro do OnModelCreating.

Comment: Se remover a convenção resolve, quer dizer que se eu apagar o pai ou o filho relacionado à tabela, é ok que o registro da tabela tenha chaves órfãs?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi usando esse código:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConve‌​ntion>();
```

dentro do `OnModelCreating`

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, acredito que o correto seja utilizar o código abaixo na função override "OnModelCreating", dentro de sua classe que herda de DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Pois a relação citada é de um para um.